# Linear equation, standard form

Tags: linear-algebra

This linear equation

$ax_1+bx_2=c \tag{1}$

is said to be written in a "standard form". Suppose $c$ is not equal to zero.

$$\frac{a}{c}x_1+\frac{b}{c}x_2=1$$

or

$\alpha x_1+\beta x_2=1 \tag{2}$

The equation (1) is equivalent to the equation (2). And the equation (2) seems to be neater than the equation (1). My question is why the first equation is "the standard form", but not the second one? And does the second one have a name?

Comment: Equation (2) is in the standard form as much as equation (1).

Comment: Maybe it's the notion of not using fractions in standard forms....?

Comment: the second form doesn't allow c to be 0

Comment: Ok, I am not good at formulating questions. The second equation is in standard form, but it is not considered to be the general case (as there is 1 and not c). While I insist it is the general case

Comment: if $ \alpha x_1 + \beta x_2 = 1$ then for $\eta \neq 0$ then $$\alpha \eta x_1 + \beta \eta x_2 = \eta$$ Thus $\gamma x_1 + \zeta x_2 = \eta$ in standard form.

Comment: how would one represent $x+y=0$ in the second form?

Comment: The second one is called user3600124-form.